# How to store a particular portion of json in a variable based on certain condition in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json which looks like below

```
result_json = {
   "status":"Gov info",
   "user_input":[
      {
         "rule":"Location"
      },
      {
         "des": "This is for location1",
         "value": 1
      },
      {
         "des": "This is for location2",
         "value": 2
      },

      {
         "rule":"District"
      },

      {
         "des": "This is for district1",
         "value": 1
      },
      {
         "des": "This is for district2",
         "value": 2
      },

      {
         "des": "This is for district3",
         "value": 3
      },
      {
         "des": "This is for district4",
         "value": 4
      },

      {
         "rule":"Country"
      },

      {
         "des": "This is for country1",
         "value": 1
      },

      {
         "rule":"Continent"
      },
      {
         "des": "This is for continent1",
         "value": 1
      },
      {
         "des": "This is for continent2",
         "value": 2
      },
   ],
   "source":"Gov",
   "id":"5ass1"
}
```

I also have a list like so

```
lookup = [u'Location', u'District', u'Country', u'Continent']
```

Now what I want to do is that I look at each value of the list, check against the json for the same value (the value is stored against `rule` key) and get the sub json right after it until I hit the next `rule`. For example

The first value in the list lookup is `Location`. Now I loop through `user_input` key's value, check against the sub key `rule` and find out that the value `Location` matches and right after that store the subsequent dictionaries until I hit the next key `rule`. So for lookup value `Location`, after checking against the json and collecting the subsequent dictionary, this is how I will store

```
filtered_output = {  
   "Location":[  
      {  
         "des":"This is for location1",
         "value":1
      },
      {  
         "des":"This is for location2",
         "value":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I look for next lookup value which is `District` and the subsequent part of json that will be stored is

```
filtered_output = {  
   "Location":[  
      {  
         "des":"This is for location1",
         "value":1
      },
      {  
         "des":"This is for location2",
         "value":2
      }
   ],
   "District":[  
      {  
         "des":"This is for district1",
         "value":1
      },
      {  
         "des":"This is for district2",
         "value":2
      },
      {  
         "des":"This is for district3",
         "value":3
      },
      {  
         "des":"This is for district4",
         "value":4
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried doing something like below

```
filtered_output = {}
for i in lookout:
    temp_json = []
    for j in result_json["user_input"]:
        if j.get("rule") == i:
            temp_json.append(j)
```

Here it only stores the dictionary that contains the key `rule` but doesn't continue further until it hits the next `rule` key. I am not sure how to make this work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first transform your input to the format you want and them I would onluy filter the keys, something like this:

```py
user_input = result_json["user_input"]
transformed_user_input = {}

for el in user_input:
    if "rule" in el:
        current_rule = el["rule"]
        transformed_user_input[current_rule] = []
    else:
        transformed_user_input[current_rule].append(el)

lookup = [u'Location', u'District', u'Country', u'Continent']
filtered_user_input = { key: transformed_user_input[key] for key in lookup}
```

This way, you process your input only once (don't know how big it is).

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thanks buddy!